# Azure Databricks without /FileStore and /Users

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I just created a Databricks workspace on Azure and configured the access token for the Databricks CLI.

Everything works. Blob Storage mounts, JDBC database access and the CLI.

But: the filesystem looks strange. I remember that there where `/Users` and `/FileStore` under `dbfs:/` when calling `dbfs ls`. They are *missing*.

When choosing "Copy File Path" for a notebook, the path is the expected `/Users/user@ad.domain/NoteBookName` but neither path nor notebook show up when calling `dbfs ls`.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The /Users folder that you see in the Workspace for notebooks is not stored in DBFS. 
You maybe able to find the notebooks if you poke around:

```
%sh ls /
```

The FileStore is stored in DBFS but created on demand (or manually).

Comment: Thanks! I remembered false. It is not `databricks fs ls` aka `dbfs ls` *but* `databricks workspace ls /Users/`. The workspaces are *not* in the `dbfs` filesystem, but on the VM disk of the driver node. You saved me a lot of head-ache and time.

Comment: Are the files in the workspace accessible in the notebooks?